# vim plugin comment blocks

Tags: c++, vim, comments

I looked around, but didn't find what I wanted.  I need a vim plugin to insert blocks of code and prompt me for values in the comment.

```
//      **********************   BeWee   ************************
//      *** Creation Date:
//      *** Last Modification Date:
//      *** File name: BeWee.cpp
//      *********************************************************
//      *** Programmer:  Name
//      *** Email: Email
//      *********************************************************
//      *** This file contains the implementation for the class
//      *** BeWee.  The class BeWee models ...
//      ***
//      *********************************************************
```

I want to be prompted to enter the BeWee, Creation Data, etc

I currently have these comments in a file and just read them into the vim editor.

TIA

Comment: Just a note, but I have vim automatically fill in the creation data when I make a new file.   The modification date could probably be done likewise (when you write the file, perhaps?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540). Follow the install guide and make a snippet with the layout.

Comment: Documentation is pretty much the entire reason I use snipmate.  Saves so much time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably You are looking for template engine for vim.

Try [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2611)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion [TSkeleton.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1160) could help you to do what you want. It can load the skeleton that you will have made and let you modify the different parts (values) on the fly.